# Binomial and direct probability calculation

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

i have this problem:

> a careless bookseller mixture 4 broken books with 16 normal ones from one specific book. Four friend go to his library to buy this book.
>   a) Calculate the probability of 3 of the 4 friends take the broken books and one get the normal one.
>   b) What is the probability of after the friends go to these library it remains with the same amount of broken books?

If i try to solve this problem by bernoulli, we have:

a) if $X$ = number of broken books

$x ~ B(n, p) = {n \choose k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1 - p)^{n-k}$

$x ~ B (20, 1/5)$

if $k$ = number of success of the Bernoulli, which is get a broken book

$B(20, 1/5) = {20 \choose 3} \cdot (1/3)^3 \cdot (4/5)^{17} = 0,20536$

And if i calculates the probability by hand, i got:

$B$ =  broken book

$N$ = normal book

i want $BBBN$

so:

$P = \frac{4}{20} \cdot \frac{3}{19} \cdot \frac{2}{18} \cdot \frac{16}{17} \cdot \frac{4!}{3!} = 0,013209$

Does anyone knows why im getting this difference? what im doing wrong?

As the letter B is the same as letter A, i just post the question for letter A

Comment: Binomial distribution is not exactly the correct model because subjects are selecting books 'without replacement'. Consider 'hypergeometric' distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment continued:** Rushing to a meeting; no time for a proper exposition.
Here are two versions of R code that solve it. Maybe you can 'decode' it.

```
dhyper(3, 4, 16, 4)
## 0.01320949
choose(4,3)*choose(16,1)/choose(20,4)
## 0.01320949
```

---

Added later, after Acceptance, for completeness.

Total number of ways in which 4 friends can each select a book from
among 20 is ${20 \choose 4} = \frac{20}{4!\, 16!} = 4845.$
Total number of ways in which 3 friends can each select a damaged book from among 4 is ${4 \choose 3} = 4.$
Total number of ways in which 1 friend can select a normal book from among 16 is ${16 \choose 1} = 16.$

Probability exactly 3 friends select damaged book and 1 selects a normal book
is $\frac{64}{4845} = 0.01320949.$

Let $X$ be the number of friends who happen to select damaged books. It has
the hypeergeometric distribution tabled below.

```
 x = 0:4;  pdf = dhyper(x, 4, 16, 4)
 cbind(x, pdf)
     x          pdf
  ## 0 0.3756449948
  ## 1 0.4623323013
  ## 2 0.1486068111
  ## 3 0.0132094943  <-- Answer
  ## 4 0.0002063983
```